# Compare two files in Linux: ignoring first and last lines

Tags: linux, comparison, diff

I´d like to compare two files, but I don´t want to take into account the first 10 lines, and the last 3 lines of both files. I tried to do it with diff and tail commands, like in [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/111217/Linux-UNIX/Command-compare-files-starting-line), but without success.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use GNU `tail` and `head`:

To ignore the first 10 lines of a file, use `tail` like this:

```
tail -n +11 file
```

To ignore the last 3 lines of a file, use `head` like this:

```
head -n -4 file
```

You can then construct your `diff` command using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) as follows:

```
diff <(tail -n +11 file | head -n -4) <(tail -n +11 file2 | head -n -4)
```

Comment: Head not always works, you may want to use a sed one liner : `sed '1,11 d'`

Comment: How would you do that with a directory with multiple files in it?